# ag-grid Angular custom sort parameters showing as undefined

Tags: sorting, ag-grid

I've set the following comparator on `columnDef`

```js
...
comparator: (date1: string, date2: string): number => this.dateComparator(date1,date2),
...
```

and have a custom function to sort strings as dates as below

```js
dateComparator(date1: string, date2: string): number {
    const d1 = new Date(date1);
    const d2 = new Date(date2);
    //custom logic and return..
}
```

However, the `date1` and `date2` parameters are `undefined`. can someone help with this please.

Comment: The parameters for `comparator` are the following: comparator(valueA, valueB, nodeA, nodeB, isInverted). Any chance you are using custom renderer or formatter function for that column? Then you would probably want to use the nodeA and nodeB params instead of valueA or valueB.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code snippets. Please add more code or ideally a complete [minimal reproducible exmple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) hosted on plunker or codesandbox.

Comment: @MattNienow, Thank you for the clue. the documentation is a bit confusing. But the underlying issue was I had a custom renderer which was causing issue, resolved by adding a ```valueGetter```

Answer (score 0):

I have written the same comparator

```
export function dateComparator(date1: string, date2: string) {
    const date1Number = date1 ? new Date(date1).getTime() : null;
    const date2Number = date2 ? new Date(date2).getTime() : null;

    if (date1Number === null && date2Number === null) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (date1Number === null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (date2Number === null) {
        return 1;
    }
    return date1Number - date2Number;
}
```

But if you change your value of the cell in some cases (from date to string - like in my case if date is null I am showinng 'Never Logged' then we should replace it) - and showing just a string you can use the next comparator:

```
export function dateComparator(date1: string, date2: string) {
    const neverLog = 'Never Logged';

    const date1Number = date1 === neverLog ? null : new Date(date1).getTime();
    const date2Number = date2 === neverLog ? null : new Date(date2).getTime();
    if (date1Number === null && date2Number === null) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (date1Number === null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (date2Number === null) {
        return 1;
    }
    return date1Number - date2Number; }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are not sure whether the date value which is being passed in the comparator is valid string or not then you can check it first and sanitize it before comparing.

```
function dateComparator(date1, date2) {
  var date1Number = validateDateinput(date1);
  var date2Number = validateDateinput(date2);
  if (date1Number === null && date2Number === null) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (date1Number === null) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (date2Number === null) {
    return 1;
  }
//custom logic and return..
  return date1Number - date2Number;
}

function validateDateinput(date) {
  // handle null and undefined values. add more logic here as per use case
  if (date === undefined || date === null) {
    return null;
  }
  //string is valid to create date
  return new Date(date);
}
```